# How to route to next page after successful payment in MERN app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, payment-gateway, payment, paytm

I am using Paytm payment gateway for transaction. My front-end is in reactjs and backend is in nodejs and expressjs. I wanted that after successful payment next page is redirected.

Backend Code-
for checking checksum and transaction.

```
    PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(JSON.stringify(paytmParams.body), paytmconfig.merchantkey).then(function(checksum){
        paytmParams.head = {

            "signature" : checksum
        };
        var post_data = JSON.stringify(paytmParams);
        var options = {
            /* for Staging */
            hostname: 'securegw-stage.paytm.in',
            /* for Production */
            // hostname: 'securegw.paytm.in',
            port: 443,
            path: '/v3/order/status',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': post_data.length
            }
        };
        // Set up the request
        var response = "";
        var post_req = https.request(options, function(post_res) {
            post_res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                response += chunk;
            });

            post_res.on('end', function(){
                console.log('Response: ', response);
                res.write(response)
            });
        });
        // post the data
        post_req.write(post_data);
        post_req.end();
    });
```

Front-end code:
will call onPayment function for making the payments

```
onPayment= async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            var amount="1.00";
            var mobile_number="+919999999999";
            var email="abcd@gmail.com";
            var orderId="ORDER_ID"+(new Date().getTime());
            let params={
                orderId:orderId,
                email:email,
                amount:amount,
                mobile_number:mobile_number
            }
            var url="http://localhost:4000/payment/paynow";
            var request={
                url:url,
                params:params,
                method:"get"
            }

            const response = await Axios(request);
            const processParams=await response.data;
            console.log(processParams);

            var details={
                action : "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process",
                // params : params
                params : processParams
            }

            this.post(details);

        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'


const history = useHistory()


history.push('yourNextPage', {details:detail})
```

either history.replace should work:

```
history.replace('yourNextPage', {details:detail})
```

**EDIT**

{details:detail} is in case you want to pass your next page a state from the previous page

if you dont want to pass any state

it would be enough

```
history.push('yourNextPage')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the code available on the below repository for checksum in node.js.

https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_Node_Checksum

You can also refer the below repository for react (front-end)

https://github.com/paytm/paytm-blink-checkout-react